# Cleaning up the "sync" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [sync](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sync) tag is a bit of a mess. It *mostly* contains questions about triggering an off-camera flash (e.g. [1](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/126367/why-is-my-canon-drebel-not-syncing-with-my-off-camera-flash-when-using-a-camera), [2](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/93946/are-there-3-5mm-male-to-male-flash-sync-cables)) but also contains questions about synchronising files between different locations (e.g. [3](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/128141/sync-photos-in-adobe-lightroom-cc)) and flash/shutter synchronisation (e.g. [4](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/100597/high-speed-sync-and-sony-nex-3k-with-jjc-msa-10-adapter)).

How should we clean this up?

Answer (score 2):

I propose to:

- Retag the questions about file synchronisation with a new [file-sync](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-sync) tag.
- Retag the two questions about flash/shutter synchronisation with the existing [sync-speed](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sync-speed) tag.
- Leave the questions about triggering off-camera flashes with the [sync](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sync) tag and add appropriate tag descriptions.

Comment: Sorry Philip, missed this for a few days. I completely support this. Perhaps even extending your 3rd point to use `flash-sync` if further clarity is needed, and merging the remaining `sync` into `flash-sync`. Suggestion only, if you don't agree, no worries. I still support this 100%.